# Predictive accuracy and correlation of inputs

Tags: regression, correlation, prediction

I am reading [Judgement under Uncerntainty](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521284147) and in p.65 it is stated that in the normal linear model, correlation of input variables decreases the predictive accuracy (in contrast to the human perception which is exactly the opposite). I can't put a specific quote because the meaning is scattered over the [whole page](http://books.google.de/books?id=_0H8gwj4a1MC&lpg=PP1&dq=judgement%20under%20uncertainty&pg=PA65#v=onepage&q=judgement%20under%20uncertainty&f=false). I am having trouble understanding this statement. Can anyone help?

Comment: If I read correctly, it says "linear model [)] in which expected predictive accuracy is independent of within-profile variability." If I understand correctly, the rest of the page deals with predictions made by humans.

Comment: the next paragraph is the one that describes the paradox between linear model and perception of accuracy in humans in the setting of  correlations between inputs. I understand the human perception part. I dont knwo where the part of the linear model comes from (my question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If inputs are correlated in the linear models, it will be become more difficult to isolate the effect of individual variables to the outcome. This is called the multicollinearity problem and is shown with big standard errors in the coefficients of affected variables.

For prediction this can pose a problem if your X variable is outside the range of variation as compared to the situation where you estimated your parameter values.

Actually, Nobel prize-winner Trygve Haavelmo wrote about this issue, warning against models where there is a lack of autonomy in the economic relations. This was published in 1944 in the "Econometrica" as an article called "Probability approach in Econometrics".